# Question on James Norris' Notes on Advanced Probability

Tags: probability, analysis, probability-theory, random-variables

This was talked about in the notes (see for instance D. Chua's notes for the course taught by M. Lis, which was based on the same class), and I don't understand why it is true.

Basically, suppose $(X, W)$ are Gaussian random variables, and our goal (quoting D. Chua's notes) is to compute the conditional expectation $E(X|W)$. Suppose we random variable $Y$ such that $EX = EY$, $X - Y$ is independent of $W$, and $Y$ is $W$-measurable, then $Y = E(X|W)$, since $E(X - Y)1_A = 0$ for all $\sigma(W)$-measurable $A$.

My question is: I know we are supposed to use $X - Y$ being independent of $W$ together with $EX = EY$ over entire probability space $\Omega$ to show $E(X - Y) 1_A = 0$ for all $\sigma(W)$-measurable $A$, where $1_A$ is the indicator function, but I cannot figure out how to do it.

Comment: I don't see a question here.

Comment: You are absolutely right. Amended it now.

Answer (score 1):

For your question the answer is $I_A$ is independent of $X-W$ so $E(X-W)I_A=E(X-W)P(A)=0$.

However, you don't have to go through the definition of conditional expectation to find $E(X|W)$. Choose $a$ such that $E[(X-aW)W]-E(X-aW)EW=0$. Then $E(X|W)=E(X-aW)|W)+E(aW|W)=EX-aEW+aW$ because $X-aW$ and $W$ are independent. [ If jointly normal random variables have covariance $0$ then they are independent].

Comment: Oh! With regards to your first sentence, that's what I was thinking, but I could not show from the definition that $I_A$ is independent of $X - W$ (I know it's a really basic question sorry). So basically, I know that independent random variables are independence of random variables $X, Y$ means (definition from Durrett Probability) that for all $C, D \in \mathcal{R}$, we have $P(X \in C, Y \in D) = P(X \in C) P(Y \in D)$, i.e., the events $A = {X \in C}$ and $B = {Y \in D}$ are independent, but how does that show us $I_A$ and $X - w$ are independent (like how do we get the indicator function?

Comment: @PhysicsEnthusiast If $X$ and $Y$ are independent then so are $X$ and $f(Y)$ for any measurable function $f:\mathbb  R \to \mathbb  R$. Also any random variable measurable w.r.t. $\sigma(W)$ can be written as $f(W)$ for some measurable function $f:\mathbb  R \to \mathbb  R$.